# Is there an SVG version of the CV logo?

Tags: support, images

SVG versions of a few logos are available [here](https://stackapps.com/q/347). Is there an SVG version of the CrossValidated logo available somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the SVG logo as it's shown on the site: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stats/img/sprites.svg

It comes with several other sprites attached, so you'll need to [crop the SVG file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31575/) to get just the logo.

Comment: Do you know where I could get the black-and-white meta version?

Comment: Thanks! I tried the same thing but I guess I didn't inspect the right piece.